# ERD - Modelling can-be Relationship

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I'm searching for a solution to model a "can-be" relationship.
E.g.: A `User` can be `Special User`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you're looking for subtypes/supertypes.

Answer (score 0):

Types for entities can be viewed (results) as one of the following two things:

- Relationships
- Fields

The types that results in fields are usually seen as functional redundancy, where different rows/records in a table can have the same type. For example, the sex/gender of a user, or access privileges or permission level from a user as well.

If, however, this field has attributes/properties, so we have a new entity. In this case, users would be relating to, for example, address, which may have the street name, house number, among other things. Or, in your case, if Special User has attributes/properties, we have a "Special Users" entity. The cardinality here depends on how many types a user can have, and that takes into account the problem context.

As you say that a user "can be", it means it "can not be" too. You could:

- Set a nullable functional redundancy field in Users entity or,
- Set an entity "Types of Users" and create a relationship N-N for
  "Users". In this case, you would have an intermediate table that
  would allow or not the connection between the two entities.

In both approaches you have the ability to add new types of users in the future without effort.

There is a third case, however, referred to as partitioning, where we have types and subtypes of entities. In this case, entities subtypes inherit fields of their super entities. I believe this is not your case here.

If you have any questions, please comment and I will answer.